# Серая область в GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

Проблема возникает при переходе на вкладку "Contacts" **ИЗ ДРУГИХ** вкладок.
А именно появляется серая область на карте (или карта на серой области).

Пробовал дважды инициализировать карту (с хабра) и ресайзить после загрузки(со стека), но безрезультатно.

Помогают (после этих действий карта появляется полностью):

- рефреш страницы,
- переключение вкладок БРАУЗЕРА,
- вызов и изменение размеров "панели отладки" GoogleChrome

Вот адрес http://lololo.tk

Answer (score 2):

> вызов и изменение размеров "панели отладки" GoogleChrome

Вернее ресайз страницы. Изменение размеров окна тоже помогает, скорее всего проблема исчезает при запуске какого-нибудь OnResize.

Замечу, что при переходе из соседней вкладки (Вы же имели ввиду меню шаблона, а не вкладки браузера? А-то я сначала не понял...) происходит красивое сворачивание области, потом в нее грузится контент, потом она разворачивается. При загрузке с нуля область изначально развернута.

Таким образом при загрузке с нуля размер карты высчитывается корректно, а при загрузки аяксом — нет, так как высота области загрузки равна 0. При изменении размера или переключении вкладок браузера (кстати в вебките переключение вкладок браузера не дает нужный эффект) происходит OnResize и размер карты перерасчитывается, а сама она отображается заново и теперь корректно, так как высота ее уже не 0.

Как вариант можно загружать карту уже после разворачивания основной области в див с opacity: 0 и потом, когда она загрузилась, показывать див каким-нибудь красивым эффектом типа animate из жуквери. На задний план можно запилить вращающуюся гифку. (ну это все ИМХО, ибо опыта в таких вещах у меня не хватает, чтобы говорить, что так делать хорошо или полхо).

**Добавлено:**
И да, кстати, кнопка Increase map тоже не обновляет ее размеров. Так что если на нее нажать, серое поле появится справа.

Comment: по поводу Increase Map, то серая область появляется не на всю ширину увеличения, а на меньшее число пикселов (что странно).

Comment: Скорее всего дело в том, что загруженное изображение карты больше, чем тот его кусок, который Вы видете. Так что он просто показывает то, что скрыто но загружено, а то, что не загружено — серый фон.

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

- 1.Вынес функцию initializing(загрузкa карты) в файл
         map.php
- 2.Добавляю в **#contenблок ***'#map_canvas'***, после "разворота" страницы
- 3.Загружаю в #map_canvas аяксом map.php, и на коллбэк вешаю анимацию
         появления

Проблему при увеличении решил просто вызовом в коллбэке анимации функции initializing()